# R: Text Mining, create list of words per document

Tags: r, tidyverse, text-mining, tidytext

I am reading in the text from a number of PDFs in a directory.
Then, I split these texts into single words (tokens) using the `tidytext::unnest_tokens()`-function.
Can someone please tell me, how I can add an additional column to the `test`-tibble with the name of the file each word comes from?

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
content <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
list <- unlist(content, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
df = data.frame(text = list)

test <- df %>% tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following. Instead of using `unlist` with all the files, instead pass the entire list of files to `map_df` from `purrr`. Then, you can add a column with `filename` along with the `word` column.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")

map_df(files, ~ data.frame(txt = pdf_text(.x)) %>%
         mutate(filename = .x) %>%
         unnest_tokens(word, txt))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
content <- stack(sapply(files, pdf_text, simplify = FALSE))
df %>% 
   tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

the plyr package as a nice function for binding to df and using list names as new columns:

```
library(pdftools)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
content <- lapply(files, pdf_text) 
# set list name acording to files
names(content) <- files 
list <- unlist(content, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

# use the acorind function from plyr packages and check the result
plyr::ldply(list)
```